# Problem with maximizing windows on extended desktop (2 monitors)

Tags: compiz, window

I'm running Mint 11, with Compiz activated. I have extended desktop over 2 monitors. But I have issues when I need to maximize windows – it's stretched over 2 monitors, not inside one. I know that worked before installing ATI Catalyst. Any idea how to fix it? Is this a Compiz issue or?

Comment: It sounds like your display driver isnt advertising xinerama info. Xinerama is what applications use to determine how your monitors are layed out.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed Ati Catalyst, it replaced your Xorg.conf file with it's own. Odds are you can use the Catalyst UI to recreate your old settings and save it's new Xorg.conf file, or potentially Catalyst left an Xorg.conf.backup laying around, although it would be loading the wrong video drivers so you would need to edit that by hand as well ;)

I would stick with these Docs in your circumstances,
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI_Catalyst#ATI_Catalyst_Control_Center